# Add barplot layer to the heatmap (geom_tile)

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, heatmap

So, as said in the header, I want to add 1 more visual layer to my heatmap.
[image: Input]

Sample data is from `mpg`.

```
library(tidyverse) # for dplyr and ggplot2

data <- mpg %>% 
    mutate(quantity = 1, isnew = ifelse(year == 2008, 1, 0)) %>% 
    group_by(drv, class) %>% 
    summarise(quantity = sum(quantity), isnew = round(sum(isnew) / quantity, 2))
```

Two categories as main axis - class and drv.
Quantity is just a number of cars for each intersection of class and drv.
Isnew is a share of new cars (year 2008 vs 1999) in quantity.

```
     drv      class quantity isnew
   <chr>      <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1     4    compact       12  0.67
 2     4    midsize        3  0.67
 3     4     pickup       33  0.52
 4     4 subcompact        4  0.00
 5     4        suv       51  0.53
 6     f    compact       35  0.40
 7     f    midsize       38  0.50
 8     f    minivan       11  0.45
 9     f subcompact       22  0.50
10     r    2seater        5  0.60
11     r subcompact        9  0.56
12     r        suv       11  0.55
```

Heatmap

```
ggplot(data, aes(class, drv)) + 
    geom_tile(aes(fill = quantity)) + 
    geom_text(aes(label = isnew))
```

What i wish to achieve is to change text values on each section to stacked bars.
Top chunk of every bar must be transparent, to save the initial colors of heatmap. Bottom one must represent the `isnew` value of that sector of the heatmap.

Draw some part (just couple bars, but i want them all) of the desired output in Paint 8p

[image: Output]

Found [in here](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2012/09/visualize-complex-data-with-subplots.html) that it probably can be done via `ggsubpolot` package. But it seems deprecated, and "Embed into ggplot2 graphics" as stated at Grolemund github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plot seems pretty confusing to me, but I couldn't resist taking a crack at making it. We use `geom_segment` to create the bars and we use the underlying `drv` factor codings to place the bars and the text labels in the proper locations on the y-axis.

```
ggplot(data, aes(class, drv)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = quantity), colour="white", size=0.5) + 
  geom_segment(aes(y=as.numeric(as.factor(drv)) - 0.5, 
                   yend=as.numeric(as.factor(drv)) - 0.5 + isnew,
                   x=class, xend=class),
               colour="yellow", size=10) +
  geom_text(aes(label = isnew, y=(2*as.numeric(as.factor(drv)) + isnew)/2 - 0.5),
            colour="grey30", size=3) + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Perhaps using `geom_point` with a size aesthetic would be better:

```
ggplot(data, aes(class, drv)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = quantity), colour="white", size=0.5) + 
  geom_point(aes(size=isnew), shape=21, fill="white") +
  scale_size_continuous(range=c(1,10)) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]